# Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both XXX and XXX,One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After I update the newest version(2017.1) app on my mac-pro, when I run a java program, the console always show following warning. How can I fix this warning?

> objc[2163]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   (0x10ba504c0) and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib
>   (0x10cab54e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have both a JDK and a JRE in your classpath, probably as your runtime environment, This is ambiguous and should be remedied.